# How do I get the height of a DOM element once the page has loaded in a Backbone / Marionette application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone / Marionette layout with a few views in it. I need to adjust the height of two views (essentially, two divs currently with different heights) to be the same.

I used the `$(document).ready(function () {});` just before the closing body tag and after all the scripts that handle loading of the views to fetch the height but it outputs null. Why is that? How do I get the heights of the following CompositeViews when the page has completed loading?

```
List.TopQueries = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#topqueries-template",
itemView: List.QueryItem,
className: "block blue",

appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
  // Do something here
},
onRender: function () {
  // Do something here
},

onClose: function () {
  // do something here
}
});

List.FailedQueries = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#failedqueries-template",
itemView: List.QueryItem,
className: "block red",

appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
  // Do something here
},
onRender: function () {
  // Do something here
},

onClose: function () {
  // Do something here
}
});
```

Comment: just as an opposite way of resolve issue, could you please describe a bit view structure, thinking about resolve this issue with plain css

Comment: @Evgeniy I edited the question with the views.

Comment: is this close to what you r going to reach http://jsfiddle.net/eq3dhL1y/1/ ? is html markup close to your output ?

Comment: From a layout perspective, this is my intended output. I used the Chrome inspector to apply those properties to my layout but it didn't work.

Comment: could you please attach your html output + css you have - better make it in fiddle and attach link

Answer (score 1):

For anything regarding checks in the UI that should be already attached to the DOM (like checking sizes of some divs as in your case), you shoud use the "onDomRefresh" event

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    onDomRefresh: function(){
    // manipulate the `el` here. it's already
    // been rendered, and is full of the view's
    // HTML, ready to go.
    }
});
```

If you need to "wait" until certain views within your Layout have been rendered and fully attached to the DOM, you should listen to the `onDomRefresh` of those views, not the one of the Layout.

The `onDomRefresh` of the Layout will be triggered when the Layout itself is fully attached to the DOM. It won't wait until all its child regions have shown a view (after all, you can show/close views in the Layout child regions at any moment, so that wouldn't have much sense).

(I thought you were asking about Marionette Layouts, thus the explanation above, I leave it there as it might be worth knowing).

Nevertheless, what Evgeniy suggests about using CSS to handle the problem with no need of Javascript may be a better approach to solve your specific problem (what I answered is the leading question: *How do I get the height of a DOM element once the page has loaded in a Backbone / Marionette application?*)

Comment: How do I compare the heights of two CompositeViews and set them both to be of equal height? I need to compute which one is taller and set the height of the shorter one to that of the taller one. How would i do that if I only handle the onDomRefresh event in one view?

Comment: I thought you were talking about Marionette Layouts, so I explained a bit more in the answer.
Now I see you are talking about two different composite views, so you should listen for onDomRefresh on both views! :)

Comment: How would I access the computed height of one view inside the onDomRefresh event of another view?

Comment: That is not really a good approach. What you should have is a "parent" view (such as a Layout, what I thought you were using), and handle the onDomRefresh of your child views from there.

Comment: Though, if this approach seems too much for your specific problem, you might want to think about fixing it with CSS.

Comment: I can't modify the codebase at large. This is for a client. Is there any way to simply use the $(document).ready(function() {}); anywhere? How would I solve this with CSS? I tried @Evgeniy approach above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59155/discussion-between-john-and-nagarjun).